# ExtJS gauge chart series - setValue() is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I have a piece of code looking like this:

```
var myChart = this.items[i].items[j].down().down();
myChart.series.items[0].setValue(30);
```

myChart is well defined. When I spy it in firebug, it contains the chart.

I understood that gauge is not a type of chart but a type of series, so I really don't understand why I get the error "setValue is not a function" !

If someone could help, it would be really cool cause I'm very annoyed with that.

Here's my view definition:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.portlet.GaugePortlet', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.gaugeportlet',
    height: 300,
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.JsonStore',
        'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
        'Ext.chart.series.Series',
        'Ext.chart.series.Line',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
        'Ext.chart.*',
        'Ext.chart.axis.Gauge',
        'Ext.chart.series.*'],

    initComponent: function () {

        Ext.apply(this, {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: {
                xtype: 'chart',
                animate: {
                    easing: 'elasticIn',
                    duration: 1000
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                axes: [{
                    type: 'gauge',
                    position: 'gauge',
                    minimum: 0,
                    maximum: 2,
                    steps: 10
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'gauge',
                    donut: false,
                    colorSet: ['#F49D10', '#ddd']
                }]
            }
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

I don't want to work with dynamic stores for now, I just want to test with setting an hardcoded value.

Thanks

Comment: What firebugs tells you about myChart.series.items[0] ? can you output this?

Comment: It ouputs me this: Object { type="gauge", field="valeur", donut=false, more...} The values set in my view on the "series" block. But according to the ExtJS documentation, the setValue function is available for series type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this error by using setValue in my view's afterLayout event.

So my code looks like this now:

```
//view declaration...
listeners:
{
    afterlayout: function ()
    {
        //use setValue here.
    }
}
```

Finally I'm facing an other issue... I have no more error in firebug but visually, my gauge chart is not displaying any value. It is well rendered, but it is empty.... I tried to update it using the doLayout() or doComponentLayout() methods, but still nothing happens.